# Creating Azure Pipeline Build and Release using a script

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to implement azure pipeline including Build and Release pipeline via a template or script.
At the moment we have the yaml files on a git repo and need to upload them on the Azure DevOps console manually.

I couldn't find any documentation regarding automating this process in Azure website, maybe they don't have any yet? I know that Jenkins has a template for it's pipeline setup.

As I googled I found someone last year mentioned using PowerShell script or AzurePipelinePS here. However I couldn't find any details info about how to use AzurePipelinePS to Get-APBuildDefinition and Publish-APBuildDefinition.

Azure Cli for pipeline with a bash script can also be a solution.

Can someone help me with this? Or if there is any better solution than using PowerShell scripts?

Updated:

Here is what I have tried:
build.json file

```
{
"process": {
    "phases": [
        {
            "steps": [
                {
                    "task": "SonarQubePrepare@4",
                    "inputs": {
                      "env1": "v1",
                      …
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "task": "Gradle@2",
                    "inputs": {
                      "tasks": "build",
                      …
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "task": "Docker@2",
                    "inputs": {
                      "containerRegistry": "mycontainerregistery",
                      "repository": "myrepo",
                      "command": "buildAndPush",
                      "Dockerfile": "**/Dockerfile",
                      "tags": "$(Build.BuildId)"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "task": "Bash@3",
                    "inputs": {
                      "targetType": "inline",
                      "script": "ls\nls --all build/libs\necho buildid= $(Build.BuildId)\necho tag=$(git describe --tags)\n"
                    }
                  }

            ],
            "name": "Phase 1",
            "refName": "Phase_1",
            "condition": "succeeded()",
            "target": {
                "executionOptions": {
                    "type": 0
                },
                "allowScriptsAuthAccessOption": false,
                "type": 1
            },
            "jobAuthorizationScope": "projectCollection",
            "jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes": 1
        }
    ],
    "type": 1
},
"repository" : {
    "properties": {
      "cleanOptions": "0",
      "labelSources": "0",
      "labelSourcesFormat": "$(build.buildNumber)",
      "reportBuildStatus": "true",
      "gitLfsSupport": "false",
      "skipSyncSource": "false",
      "checkoutNestedSubmodules": "false",
      "fetchDepth": "0"
    },
    "clean" : null,
    "defaultBranch": "master",
    "checkoutSubmodules" : false,
    "type" : "GitHub",
    "id" : "myorg/myrepo",
    "url": "https://github.com/myorg/myrepo"
},
"processParameters": {},
"drafts": [],
"queue": {
    "id": 324,
    "name": "ownPC",
    "pool": {
        "id": 23,
        "name": "ownPC"
    }
},
"name": "definitionCreatedByRESTAPI",
"type": "build",
"queueStatus": "enabled"
}
```

bash script:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u myusername:mypassword -d @build.json https://dev.azure.com/myorg/myproject/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=5.1
```

I get this error message:

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: definition.Steps[0]","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using this scripts:

build.json:

```
{
"name": "definitionCreatedByRESTAPI",
"queueStatus": "enabled",
"repository" : {
    "defaultBranch" : "master",
    "properties": {
        "shortName" : "myreponame",
        "reportBuildStatus" : "true",
        "apiUrl" : "https://api.github.com/repos/myorg/myreponame",
        "orgName" : "myorg",
        "safeRepository" : "myorg/myreponame",
        "refsUrl" : "https://api.github.com/repos/myorg/myrepo/git/refs",
        "connectedServiceId" : "myconnectedserviceId",
        "fullName" : "myorg/myreponame",
        "cloneUrl" : "https://github.com/myorg/myrepo.git",
        "defaultBranch" : "master"
      },
    "type" : "GitHub",
    "checkoutSubmodules" : false,
    "clean" : null,
    "id" : "myorg/myreponame",
    "url" : "https://github.com/myorg/myrepo.git",
    "name" : "myorg/myreponame"
},
"processParameters": {},
"drafts": [],
"queue": {
    "name" : "Hosted Ubuntu 1604",
    "pool" : {
       "name" : "Hosted Ubuntu 1604",
       "isHosted" : true,
       "id" : 8
    }
},
"triggers" : [
    {
       "pathFilters" : [],
       "branchFilters" : [],
       "maxConcurrentBuildsPerBranch" : 1,
       "settingsSourceType" : 2,
       "batchChanges" : false,
       "triggerType" : "continuousIntegration"
    },
    {
       "forks" : {
          "enabled" : true,
          "allowSecrets" : true
       },
       "triggerType" : "pullRequest",
       "settingsSourceType" : 2,
       "requireCommentsForNonTeamMembersOnly" : false,
       "isCommentRequiredForPullRequest" : false,
       "pathFilters" : [],
       "branchFilters" : [
          "+master"
       ]
    }
 ],
 "type" : "build",
 "process" : {
    "type" : 2,
    "yamlFilename" : "azure-pipelines.yml"
 },
 "jobTimeoutInMinutes" : 60
```

}

and then running this curl command:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u myusername:mytoken -d @build.json https://dev.azure.com/myazuredevopsorg/myazuredevopsproject/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=5.1
```

I send a GET request to get build definition of one of my existing build so that I could modify it for a new build definition that I wanted:

```
$ curl -X GET -u myusername:mytoken https://dev.azure.com/myazuredevopsorg/myazuredevopsproject/_apis/build/definitions/mydefinitionId | json_pp
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no way to deploy the yaml directly, however you should be able to use the DevOps REST API to either [create a release definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) or [a build definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have tried to use it, can you please check the updated part of the question and let me know if you know what the problem is?